# Sharing and adding to shareable code

Tags: c#

I know about sharing code using a class library(DLL) but what if I want to add code to the class from multiple winforms projects? For instance in one project I created an excel class to fill cells from a recordset then save a file, etc. But now I have another project where I want to read files and the cell contents.

This class currently resides with the original project but now of course I'd like to take that class and add to it from another project and still have it available for any other project. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not really clear how you're structuring your code or what the actual problem is, but you could keep related projects in the same solution and maintain the common code there.

Comment: ~Have a look at [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), although that might not be exactly what you're looking for.~

And I wanted to add what @david said: have the project containing the common code available in the solution (or both solutions) and reference it from there. Please take some time to have a look at Unit Testing and how to assure you don't break functionality across projects.

Comment: Partial classes only work within the same assembly.

Comment: Partial classes aren't relevant here.

Comment: Have all of your projects `reference` the DLL project. But it's unclear what your asking.

Comment: There are two options: the answer below to add an existing project (simplest), but that doesn't scale well.  What does scale is a nuget feed for your shared dlls, but requires a lot more work to set up.

Comment: If the projects aren't related (different clients) I wouldn't have them in the same solution would I? Or should I just have all similar projects in one solution and share classes where applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a project across multiple solutions, in Visual Studio's *Solution Explorer*, right click your solution and select *Add* > *Existing Project* and find your project's `.csproj` file.

Be aware that this method allows you to break your original solution without realising.  I keep all related projects within one single Solution, each of the projects can be compiled into separate applications or `.dll` files that can be shared between these applications.  Hitting Build then builds all the projects making sure that changes aren't breaking without my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to this project from another project. Right-click project, click Add, then click Reference.